# how to use (inAppBrowser) plugin in phonegap project?

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

i install "inAppBrowser" plugin in my phonegap project by this command line:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

and in the index.html blow code in writen:

```
<a id="eghdamat_ghabl" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes'); return false;">click me</a>
```

**but it does't open the link**.

config.xml:

```js
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^3.0.0" />
 
 <icon src="icon.png" />
 <splash src="splash.png" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this line on the config.xml to allow navigation to external urls

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

This will allow navigation to any external url.

If you just want to allow the navigation to apache then add this line

```
<allow-navigation href="https://apache.org" />
```